# Class Cast Exception Generics Reflection ParameterizedType

Tags: java, generics, reflection, classcastexception

I have looked for an answer on Stack for a while. All the answers look like they say I already have the right answer, but I still keep getting a class cast exception for the first line in the constructor below.

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at com.domain.security.logging.ElsAbstractCrudClass.<init>(ElsAbstractCrudClass.java:54)
```

Here's the code. After looking at the documentation I still can't figure it out. I'm relatively new to generics and reflection so need some help. TIA.

```
    public abstract class ElsAbstractCrudClass<T> {
        Class<T> entity;

        public ElsAbstractCrudClass() {

[line 54]   ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            Type type = genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            this.entity = (Class<T>) type;

        }
    }
```

Here is a subclass of the abstract crud class (SessionLog is a JPA entity):

```
@Stateless
public class SessionLogger extends ElsAbstractCrudClass<SessionLog> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ELS_Soulard_PU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @EJB
    DozerInstantiator di;
    //SessionLog entity;
    //SessionLog sessionLog = new SessionLog();
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SessionLogger.class.getSimpleName());

    public SessionLogger() {
    }
...
```

Comment: it might be useful to print out `getClass()` and `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` to see what they are

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that later today maybe or tomorrow depending on time... but I will try that.

Comment: FYI... my dev box cratered and I'm rebuilding... so I haven't been able to try this yet. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getGenericSuperclass` returns an instance of `ParameterizedType` if the super class is generic, and an instance of `Class` if it is not. Presumably you have something like:

```
class A extends B { ... }
class B extends ElsAbstractCrudClass<Person> { ... }
```

Now, `getClass()` return `A.class` with superclass `B.class`, which is not generic ...

You could generalize your code snippet to work as long as the runtime class is not generic (recursively walking the type hierarchy, replacing type parameters by their definitions as you go). However, unless you have dozens of crud classes, requiring the subclass to pass the proper class object is easier:

```
public abstract class ElsAbstractCrudClass<T> {
    final Class<T> entityClass;

    public ElsAbstractCrudClass(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class<T> is a JPA Entity class that I built. In this case I was trying to use a SessionLog.java entity class containing a single table with no relationships defined in it. I don't have anything extending it either. Would this somehow fit into this category that you describe?  I will have a good number of crud classes when I'm done, so this is why I am trying to figure out an even more generic way to do it. But if this starts turning out to be a pain in the #$@ marathon in trouble shooting, I'll revert back to your suggestion (direct assignment in the subclass) where I started. :)

Comment: Added subclass for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You got this error because EJB Container extend your Stateless bean to wrap EJB specific logic on method invocation. So at deployment time you have somthing like this:

```
ContainerSubclass extends SessionLogger {}
```

Solutions:

1) In your constructor first call

```
... = getClass().getSuperClass();
...
```

2) or code against interfaces so EJB container would create Dynamic Proxy through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run into trouble is if your extending class uses the raw type, not the generic type. In other words, this subclass will generate your exception, because its supertype is simply the raw type ElsAbstractCrudClass.

```
public class EE extends ElsAbstractCrudClass { ... }
```

But this one will not because its supertype is the generic type ElsAbstractCrudClass

```
public class EE extends ElsAbstractCrudClass<String> { ... }
```

Comment: Could you possibly take a look at my first comment to meriton's answer? Maybe it would add some insight for you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Could you please provide one or two examples of the first few lines of the concrete subclasses of ElsAbstractCrudClass? Maybe that would help.